# Regex to check Optional Group of numbers

Tags: regex, regex-group

i am trying to create a regex which should be able to accept the following strings

> proj_asdasd_000.gz.xml
>   proj_asdasd.gz.xml

basically 2nd **underscore** is optional and if any value follows it, it should only be integer.

Following is my Regex that i am trying.

```
^proj([a-zA-z0-9]?)+_[a-zA-z]+(_[0-9]?)+\.[a-z]+.[a-z]
```

Any suggestion to make it accept the above mentioned strings?

Comment: Try switching `(_[0-9]?)+` to `(_[0-9]+)?`. The way you have it now matches `_1_2_3_4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^proj[a-zA-Z0-9]*_[a-zA-Z]+(?:_[0-9]+)?\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$
^proj[a-zA-Z0-9]*_[a-zA-Z]+(?:_[0-9]+)?(?:\.[a-z]+){2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4KEMG5/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `proj` - a literal substring
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0 or more alphanumeric chars
- `_` - a `_` char
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:_[0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of an underscore followed with 1+ digits
- `\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+` = `(?:\.[a-z]+){2}` - two occurrences of `.` and 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Notes:

- `[A-z]` [matches more than just ASCII letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926)
- `([a-zA-z0-9]?)+` matches an optional character 1 or more times, which makes little sense. Either match a char 1 or more times with `+` or 0 or more times with `*`, no need of parentheses
- `(_[0-9]?)+` matches 1 or more sequences of `_` followed by a single optional digit (so, it matches `_9___1_`, for example). The quantifiers must be swapped to match an optional *sequence* of `_` and 1+ digits.